# Why does my cross domain request return the data "object Object"?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter, cross-domain, jsonp

I am trying to make a simple cross domain data request.  After receiving the data "object Object" when making the request to my external site, I figured it was a problem with the server configuration so I ran a jsonp request to a twitter json feed and got the same "object Object repeated over and over again.  Here is what I tried

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/USERNAME.json?count=10&callback=?",
   dataType: "jsonp",
   success: function(data){
   alert (data)
   }
});
```

Any ideas?  Is this code correct?

Comment: Because you are `alert`ing a value, which converts it into its string representation. The default one for an object is `[object Object]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `object Object` means you are getting `object` implemented as `Object`

This essentially mean that your jsonp request got some sort of response from the Twitter server.

To see the actual response, key in this url at your browsers address bar http://goo.gl/h3wcl

Now, to view it in browser you need to parse it.
You are *missing out on the parsing part* completely.

Here is a quick and dirty example on parsing json result using [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/gSXFG/

Answer (score 2):

```
alert({ somedata: true });
```

That will yield the same.  It's returning an object literal, not a string.  jQuery parses it for you.

Instead of alert do:

```
console.log(data);
```

Now look in your JS console and you should see an object you can inspect and drill into to see whats in it.  Whats you know whats in it you can access it's content like any other JS object.

```
alert(data.someKey);
```

Comment: when I added 'console.log(data);' I still get the objectObject in the JS console.  This isn't a problem with dashcode is it?

Comment: Dashcode?  I assumed this was in a good browser (Safari, Chrome, Firefox + Firebug).  I would say it's JS probably does not support inspection.  Which is sad.  Just hit that twitter url in your browser and see what the json looks like.